# jQuery Isotope doesn't rearrange properly after items have been dynamically adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have an isotope layout and everything - sorting and filtering and general display - works great. But I have to make the isotope items expandable on click. I did this via a span class which is hidden via JavaScript on initial page load but can be toggled via click on a different span class  `<span class='Point'>`.

This works to a certain degree: the text is toggable - but the layout doesn't resize on click, despite me including `.isotope('layout')`. The specific jQuery code looks as follows:

```
   $(".risknotes").hide(); $grid.on( 'click', '.Point', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".risknotes").toggle(2000);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('bigger');
     $grid.isotope('layout')
    });
```

Funny thing is: if I click a filter, or a sort button, everything resizes perfectly. Just not on initial load or click. I made a jsfiddle reproducing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3t2fk5aq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is jquery take a time to finish toggle `.ricknotes` but isotope relayout instantly.
You can use `complete` option of [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to handle it like this:

```
$grid.on('click', '.Point', function() {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".risknotes")
                .toggle({ duration: 200,complete: function(){ $grid.isotope('layout') } });
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .toggleClass('bigger');

        });
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much! This works perfectly!! I didn't know about that toggle/relayout time issue! 

Just one question left.. do you may know why the layout on initial load has a huge gap inbetween horizontal grid lines? The gaps vanish if i click on a button.

EDIT: nevermind, i just fixed that by including $grid.isotope('layout') after the page has loaded :)